# Determine if my application terminated due to a call to _exit()

Tags: c, exit

I can determine if my application last terminated due to a call to `exit()` by using `atexit` or a destructor function. Is there any way to determine if my application last terminated due to `_exit()`?

Comment: Substantively, no.  It is intended to terminate your program as quickly as possible.

Comment: The whole point of using `_exit()` is to bypass everything that `exit()` does.

Comment: If called from a script file (batch file in Windows) you can tell from the program's return value. At each emergency `exit` you can use a different value.

Comment: You could change the exit number of your exits (i.e. exit(1)), and run your application on the commandline. Then query the exit code of your last command (your application) using `$?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit)

> The function _exit() terminates the calling process "immediately".
> Any open file descriptors belonging to the process are closed; any children of the  process  are  inherited  by process 1, init, and the process's parent is sent a SIGCHLD signal.
>
> The  value  status is returned to the parent process as the process's exit status, and can be collected using one of the wait(2) family of calls.

and you cannot expect `atexit()` to be called. However, similarly to `exit`, a status is set and returned from `_exit` that you might want to test from a calling script, for instance. (e.g. `exit(0);` and `_exit(1);`, if the returned value is 1 you know that `_exit` was used, not `exit`.)